# Is it possible to get size of image file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, image

I am using Node.js and i need to find the size of image file (.jpeg/.jpg/SWF)? There are tools that can tell dimensions but none which can tell file size? Are there any? If yes.Kindly tell

Comment: What "size" are you searching for? The number of bytes consumed when saved on disk?

Comment: Yes that's what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the size of a file via the `fs` core module, using the `stat` command - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback. This is valid for all files, not only images.

Answer (score 0):

For a more complete version of this answer

You can get the, stats.  Below is a link of relevant stats returned.
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

The code is like so:

```
var fs = require('fs');

...

var stats = fs.lstatSync(filePath);
var out = {};
out.isDir = stats.isDirectory(); 
out.size = stats.size;
//etc.
```

Also, it should be noted that there is a much better async version of `fs.lstat`, and if you're into that, look it up.